# UUID when using Bluetooth with IOS and Arduino

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino

I'm attempting to send data between an iPad and Arduino via Bluetooth.

I read several online tutorials but I'm confused about the UUIDs used in them.

How do I find the UUIDs used by services and characteristics for the specific Bluetooth module connected to the Arduino?

Is there an AT command for this? Can they be set? Are they a constant?

This a pretty simple app and I have the Bluetooth communicating with the Arduino via the Terminal program on my Mac. The iOS app just needs to transmit and receive a few bytes of data. Do I really need all the code involved with Core Bluetooth or is there an easier way? What's the simplest, fastest way to implement 2 way communication of a few bytes via Bluetooth?

Comment: This depends a lot on what kind of BT module you are using for communication. Since you mentioned iOS it is most probably one of the BLE modules (like RFduino, RN4020, BM70...).

Comment: It's a generic HC-06 from China. No documentation.

Comment: Hmm, i don't think HC-06 is a BLE module. To communicate with iOS you would either need a BLE module or a 'classic' BT module with authentification chip (MFi needed)

Comment: you could use HM-10 or similar for example, AT commands are well documented. an example of instructable here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Iphone-bluetooth-control-arduino/

Comment: Looks like I wasted $8 on an incompatible chip. Since I have my laptop connected via Terminal, I might go the OS X route. Any guidance on what I need to do to integrate Bluetooth into an OS X app instead?

Comment: When you connect the BT module and you mac this connection will show up as a normal serial port.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a HC-06 Bluetooth module in not BLE and is not compatable with iOS devices. I have succeeded connecting it to my Mac and have written a test app using [ORSSerialPort](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort)